# long running operations using .NET core worker service - create, cancel , pause and resume operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ihostedservice, worker-service

I've written worker service using .NET hosted service feature to move long running task from request thread. I designed API as per (https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/azure/ConsiderationsForServiceDesign.md#long-running-operations) microsoft design guidelines and using rabbitmq to send messages to worker service and its working successfully. I want to have cancellation, pause and result store feature inside worker service. Could you please suggest any best practices or any sample opensource projects which implemented this feature.

Comment: _"I want to have cancellation, pause and result store feature inside worker service."_ - and what is stopping you from it?

Comment: Cancellation is _quite easy_. Your operations have to consume a `CancellationToken` parameter and regulary check this token if cancellation was requested. The worker service has to generate a `CancellationTokenSource` for each operation and provide a way to set this value. Providing the possibility to pause and resume an operation is much more complicated.

Comment: You might wanna check this [chapter](https://livebook.manning.com/book/api-design-patterns/chapter-10/) of this API Design Patterns book. It seems to be available for free.

Comment: There are many worker services running in different machine, how to intimate worker service with cancel message(contains operation id) from API. We won't get cancellation token reference in api and is it possible to send message to specific worker?.

Comment: @PraveenKumarN there are several ways to do that. The easiest one is to store some flag in a shared database, so that the worker regularly checks it. More advanced is to make the worker a listener on a pub/sub service like Redis. Either way, it won't be easy and bullet proof. Typically people do not bother with cancelation in a distributed system, they just allow the job to finish anyway. Pausing is even harder, you would need to keep a state machine representing the job somewhere. And create pause points. Because arbitrary pausing is just not doable in practice.